# Multi process PreferencesDataStore with more than one field

Tags: android, android-preferences, datastore

The example that Google give for the Multi-process version of DataStore includes just one field in settings:

```
data class Settings(
   val lastUpdate: Long
)
```

Then the update code is:

```
scope.launch {
   dataStore.updateData {
       Settings(lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis())
   }
}
```

However, this only works if I have one field.
What happens when I have two fields?
For example, my settings:

data class Settings(

```
    val bypassEnabled: Boolean,
    val clientMode: ProvisionClientMode
)
```

It won't let me do this:

```
datastore.updateData {Settings(clientMode = ProvisionClientMode.ACTIVE_MODE) }
```

because it wants values for all the fields.

I could do a "read" and clone it with a change but that just seems wrong.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dataStore.updateData { currentSettings ->
     currentSettings.copy(clientMode = ProvisionClientMode.ACTIVE_MODE)
 }
```

I think it can be solved by copying the existing one.

Comment: Well. AS seems to accept it. If all works ok I mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: I didn't test, wrote it based on this information.  [Write to a Proto DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore#proto-write)

Comment: Still get the points fro pointing me in the right direction. I didn't look at Proto because I am using it for Preferences.